# how to prevent google recaptcha from executing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, invisible-recaptcha

I have a form containing a button that will fire google invisible recaptcha. the html page I'm using looks like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onLoadRecaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="signup_form">
  <input type="text" name="fullname" value=""/>
  <div class="g-recaptcha"
    id="formSignup-recaptcha"
    data-sitekey="<?php echo $sitekey; ?>"
    data-callback="onSubmitFormSignupUser"
    data-size="invisible">
  </div>
  <button type="button" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I click the `#submitBtn`, I need to run an validation process using ajax to make sure that all the required fields are filled correctly before the google recaptcha is called/executed. here's the javscript code I'm using:

```js
var widgetId = '';

var onLoadRecaptcha = function() { 
  widgetId = grecaptcha.render('submitBtn', {
    'sitekey': $('#formSignup-recaptcha').attr('data-sitekey'),
    'callback': onSubmitFormSignupUser,
  });
};
var onSubmitFormSignupUser = function() {
  validateForm('#formSignupUser')
};

var doSubmitFormSignupUser = function(target) {
  var postData = $(target);

  $.ajax({
    url: '/signup_user',
    type: 'post',
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
      if (res.status) {
        window.location.href = '/home/signup_success';
      } else {
        console.log(res.message);
      }
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log('error', err.responseText);
    },
    complete: function() {
      grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
    }
  });
});

var validateForm = function(target) {
  var myData = $(target).serializeArray();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/is_validated',
    type: 'post',
    data: myData,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(res) {
      if (res.status) {
        doSubmitFormSignupUser(target);
      } else {
        console.log('message', res.message);
      }
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log('error', err.responseText);
    },
    complete: function() {
      grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
    }
  });
}

$('body').on('click', '#submitBtn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  grecaptcha.execute(widgetId);
});
```

and here's my php code:

```php
function is_validated()
{
  $response = [
    'status' => 0,
    'message' => '',
  ];
  echo json_encode($response);
}

function signup_user()
{
  echo 'thank you for signing up';
}
```

somehow that code doesn't work.. whenever I click on `#submitBtn`, the google recaptcha automatically appears asking the user to select all images with a bus or the likes. I don't know what is wrong with my code.. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

> **I don't know, Why are you using server side form validation with ajax.**

Because, in below line you are executing the `reCaptcha` right after click the button.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#submitBtn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  grecaptcha.execute(widgetId);
});
```

If you want to execute `reCaptcha` after the `ajax request`, Remove the line `grecaptcha.execute(widgetId);` from above block. And put here,

```
complete: function() {
      grecaptcha.execute(widgetId);
}
```

Comment: mainly because the validation is not only simple [required] rule, but I also need to check if some fields are already in the database..